# How do eject a SD card that is being used by Firefox?

Tags: hardware, firefox, google

I have had several occurrences where I dragged photos from my mounted SD card to upload to my `google plus` account but then after the photos were successfully update, my SD card was unable to be ejected when I tried.

It complained that the SD card could not be ejected because it was being used by a "Firefox" instance. When I opened up a terminal and did a `lsof` on my external SD card it showed something like this:

```
➜  ~  lsof /Volumes/NO\ NAME
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 43658 lowks   77r   REG    1,7  2660487 3802 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00293.JPG
firefox 43658 lowks   78r   REG    1,7  2746774 3884 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00294.JPG
firefox 43658 lowks   81r   REG    1,7  2552369 3968 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00295.JPG
```

When I went in and deleted the `.Trashes` folder, and did another `lsof`, it showed this:

```
➜  NO NAME  lsof /Volumes/NO\ NAME
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 43658 lowks   77r   REG    1,7  2660487 3802 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00293.JPG
firefox 43658 lowks   78r   REG    1,7  2746774 3884 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00294.JPG
firefox 43658 lowks   81r   REG    1,7  2552369 3968 /Volumes/NO NAME/.Trashes/501/DSC00295.JPG
zsh     45093 lowks  cwd    DIR    1,7    32768    2 /Volumes/NO NAME
lsof    45140 lowks  cwd    DIR    1,7    32768    2 /Volumes/NO NAME
lsof    45141 lowks  cwd    DIR    1,7    32768    2 /Volumes/NO NAME
```

Has anyone faced a similar situation ? What exactly is going on here ?

Comment: Empty the Trash. Try again.

Comment: Did that it complained that a few items could not be permanently deleted because they were being used.

Comment: Then try quit the apps that are using them. I'd be inclined in future to copy to a local location first, then move across to any 'off-site' folder. Looks like Firefox isn't properly letting go.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that is what I had to do, I am going to post a bug report to them.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1148765

Comment: It looks like a bug in Firefox.